# Convert binary string to integer value using first order functions

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Given a finite list of `0` and `1`, how can I convert them to their integer value using first order function?

The head of the list is the **least significant digit**. For instance, `1011` evaluates to `13`.

In this problem, I struggle to find both the recursive step and the base step because all depends wether it's a 0 and 1.

EDIT :

The goal is to define a function that will compute the decimal value given a binary string. An empty list should return 0 I guess, so it would be the base case.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Also, what should be returned for an empty list?

Comment: Well I need to define a function that will compute the decimal value given a binary string. An empty list should return 0 I guess, so it would be the base case.

Comment: A list can have two possible constructors, `[]` and `:`. You already said `foo [] = 0`. So what should happen with `foo (x : xs)`?

Comment: Well I need to evaluate the decimal value for the binary digit `x`. But I need to keep track of the index of x because of the way we usually convert a binary number into a decimal number (powers of 2)

Comment: Assume you had to find the value of `"1011"`. You've split it into a head and a tail, `'1'` and `"011"`. Also assume you can somehow compute the result for `"011"` as `6`. How does `6` relate to the final result of `13`?

Comment: @martin yes.
@melpomene well, `13 = 6 + convert "011"`

Comment: @PierreP. I think what melpomene was getting at there is `13 = 6 * 2 + 1`

Comment: @PierreP. That's wrong. `convert "011"` is `6`, and `6 + 6` is not `13`.

Comment: @melpomene The head is the least significant digit. The head `1` evals to `1` and the tail `011` evals to `12`

Comment: @PierreP. How do you get `12` from `6`?

Comment: @melpomene Times 2

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping up my comments:

```
convert :: [Int] -> Int
convert [] = 0
convert (x : xs) = x + 2 * convert xs
```

The base case is the empty list, returning `0`.

The recursive case follows from the fact that `x` is the least significant digit. `convert xs` (the recursive call) gives us the result for the tail of the list; to get the result of the whole list we need to multiply by 2 (to "shift over" the digits) and add `x` (0 or 1).

Answer (score 1):

Here's my initial thoughts about how to handle this situation.

```
import Data.Char (digitToInt)

myFunction :: String -> Int
myFunction = foldr step 0
    where step x y = (+) (digitToInt x) ( (*) y 2 )
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `foldr` fails the "first-order functions only" requirement.

Comment: @DanielWagner good point. I forgot that was part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input is a list of `1`s and `0`s.

```
bin2num :: [Int] -> Int
bin2num list = go list 0
  where go []     _ = 0
        go (x:xs) n = (x*(2^n)) + (go xs (n+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just double the acc and add it to the new element of the list . Easily use digitToInt to get the right list from the string _ st here . and foldl' for efficiency. This is Sanaz's answer

fromBin st = foldl' (\x acc -> x * 2 + acc ) 0 (map (digitToInt) st)